# MouseListener does not work in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, mouselistener

I am programming the game that the structure of my project is as follows :

We have an abstract class that all others are inherited from it.

```
    public abstract class Bird extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int M_weight;
        private int M_radius;
        private long M_bornTime;
        private int M_maxBirdPower;
        private BirdState M_birdState;
        private boolean B_prepareToShoot;

        public Bird(int weight, int radius, long bornTime, int maxBirdPower,
                BirdState birdState) {
            this.M_weight = weight;
            this.M_radius = radius;
            this.M_bornTime = bornTime;
            this.M_maxBirdPower = maxBirdPower;
            this.M_birdState = birdState;
            this.B_prepareToShoot = false;
            this.addMouseListener(this);
        }

        public BirdState getBirdState() {
            return M_birdState;
        }
    }
```

And some classes as RedBird that inherited from Bird class and implements abstract function as well.

```
    public class RedBird extends Bird {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public RedBird(int weight, int radius, long bornTime, int maxBirdPower,
                BirdState birdState) {
            super(weight, radius, bornTime, maxBirdPower, birdState);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Clicked");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        }
    }
```

I added an object from RedBird class in JPanel, But when i click on this object, `MouseListener` does not work. What is the problem ? Could any one give me a solution.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *"What is the problem ?"* Probably layouts and sizes.  For something beyond a WAG, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson What is WAG ?

Comment: Could you post the code where you add the `RedBird` into `JPanel`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the commitment :) . I saw it though, since I came back to the question.

Comment: MouseListener works fine for me. I second the recommendation for an [sscce](http://sscce.org). You need to put in some work to isolate the problem. Once you do that, you'll likely identify the problem and its solution yourself.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't "added" your mouse listener to any JComponent. That's why it isn't working.
In your bird class' constructor add the following code:

```
this.addMousListener(this);
```

Comment: I added `this.addMouseListener(this);` in my bird class and super class, but it is not work! :|

Comment: edit your question and place the code where you are creating the RedBird object. I can't find any error in this code.